# How to remove a specific version of Ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, lubuntu, kubuntu, ubuntu-gnome

I have a laptop with a 500 GB hard-disk. The operating systems are the following:

- **Windows 10** (broken, unable to boot, basically non-existent)
- **Lubuntu 14.04.1 LTS** (the one I want to replace with Kubuntu 16.04)
- **Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.1 LTS** (My current main system)
- **Xubuntu 15.10** (Previously main system, kept due to important data)

I would like to swap out Lubuntu with Kubuntu, but I have no idea how to remove Lubuntu.

All the uninstall guides I've seen so far show how to uninstall Ubuntu from a Windows-Ubuntu dualboot, and *not* how to uninstall a specific version of Ubuntu from a Windows-Lubuntu-Ubuntu Gnome-Xubuntu quad-boot.

So, ***how* do I uninstall Lubuntu?**

Comment: I think you're looking for [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)

Comment: Remove the Lubuntu partition and run `sudo update-grub` from your main distro. Done! :)

Comment: @AndroidDev Once again, a simple answer to a simple question. Thanks! :)

Comment: @SahibPrime - Then I'll post it as an answer. Please accept it so this question won't live on in the unanswered category :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Boot your main distro
2. Remove the Lubuntu partition using a tool of your choice, such as Gparted or Disks
3. Open a terminal
4. Run `sudo update-grub`

## Done :)

Comment: You can modify the partitions while you're using the system?

Comment: @SahibPrime - As long as it's not mounted.